# Teradata - How to handle exceptions 'Call failed' in procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, exception, teradata

All

I have a main procedure which is used to invoke other sub-procedures. I've added the 'DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION' in the main procedure. But when any exception raised in sub-procedure, the HANDLER in main procedure doesn't work.

So how can I catch exceptions generated in all sup-procedures?
vertion of my Teradata is 13.1, and the following is the simplified version of my code.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_main()
BEGIN

    -- # Handl SQLException
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        insert log table.
    END;

    CALL proc_sub();
END;
```

Thanks!

Frank Liu

Answer (score 0):

Are those errors already catched by exception handlers in the sub-procedures?

Only unhanded exceptions are propagated to the calling procedure.

You can use RESIGNAL to throw an error again.

Can you provide more details?